# Java Instantiate Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a class that takes in two parameterized types and I want to have a method that returns a new instance of one of the types. This is the class:

```
public class StateMachine<S extends State, E extends StateObject> {

    // State
    protected ArrayMap<S, E> states;
    protected E currentState;
    protected Entity entity;

    // Bits
    private Builder builder = new Builder();
    private int bitOffset;
    private boolean firstState = false;

    public StateMachine(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
        states = new ArrayMap<S, E>();
    }

    public E createState(S key) {
        // State identifiers must also be taggable
        assert (key instanceof Tag);
        if (!firstState) {
            firstState = true;
            bitOffset = key.numStates();
        }
        E state = (E) new StateObject(entity);
        state.bitOffset = bitOffset;
        state.bits.set(((Tag) key).getIndex());
        states.put(key, state);
        return state;
    }

    // Remainder omitted....

}
```

As you can see, I want to create a state and return its value based on the parameterized type. Currently, I have an `EntityState` class that extends `StateObject` and have an `EntityStateMachine` that extends `StateMachine` with the parameters `<StateIdentifier, EntityState>`. However, when I call `createState` from the `EntityStateMachine`, the returned value is not an `EntityState` but rather a `StateObject`.

How can I ensure that the returned value is casted to proper parameterized type?

Comment: "the returned value is [...] a StateObject" Yeah... That's what `new StateObject` means.

Comment: you can't create generics like that. You need a concrete `class` object to get a new instance, provided you know what constructor to call.

Comment: But I want to cast it to `E` which would be an `EntityState` in this case. Is that possible?

Comment: apparently you are confused as to what casting does. It does not change the type of an object. It changes the perception you have of it. You can't downcast any lower than the actual type of the object.

Comment: For example, you can do that: `Object a = new String(); String b = (String) a;`. Because a is a String, even if you look at it like it is an Object (String extends Object). But you can't do that: `Object a = new Object(); String b = (String) a;` because `a` is an Object, which can't be casted into a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java pattern to deal with this is to store `Class<E>`, and use its `newInstance` method, as follows:

```
// Class<E> object will be used to create new instances
private final Class<E> stateClass;
// Users will pass the class to StateMachine's constructor
public StateMachine(Entity entity, Class<E> stateClass) {
    this.entity = entity;
    this.stateClass = stateClass;
    states = new ArrayMap<S, E>();
}
```

Now you can create new state objects as follows:

```
E state = stateClass.newInstance(); // Only parameterless constructors are supported
state.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: Would this be reflection?

Comment: @FaTalCubez No, and that's the beauty of it. [`newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method does not require you to use reflection APIs to search for a constructor, and cast the `Object` result back to `E`. Its only drawback is inability to call constructors with parameters.

Comment: Thank you this is the solution!

Comment: This definitely is reflection because it must inspect the class at runtime and will throw a `RelfectiveOperationException` if the nullary constructor is unavailable, inaccessible, the class itself is uninstantiable, or you don't have the permission to complete the reflective operation. After all, `Class` is the entry point to the Reflection API.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Although this could definitely fail at runtime for the reasons that you mention, I would call this at most "reflection-light", because it does not require direct use of anything from `java.lang.reflect`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I ensure that the returned value is casted to proper parameterized type?

This is not the question you should ask. The real question is,

> How can I create an instance of a type parameter?

And the answer, of course is, "no way". You need a workaround, these are some ideas:

1. Pass an instance of `Class<YourType>` so the instance can be created reflectively.
2. Pass a factory of objects of `YourType`.
3. Pass an instance of `YourType`, define a method like `newInstance` on it and use it as a factory of more objects of the same type.